# Formatting error log using PDO

Tags: php, exception, error-logging

I would like the error log to show each error on a new line beginning with a time stamp.

Currently the errors just show up in a connected chunk.

```
catch(PDOException $e) {
        file_put_contents('logs/insert_errors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

I'm sure this is fairly simple. Just my first time working with PDO and not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: What does this have to do with PDO? Instead of a great lump of code that explains nothing of your problem, why not show an example of how you'd like the error log to look?

Comment: @Phil I accidentally pasted my credentials into it and erased a big chunk of it in a hurry. Editing it now

Comment: Will that query work outside of php, like in command-line or workbench?

Comment: @MadeOfAir This is just the part of it that deals with the error logging that my question is related to. There is more to it though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply format the string to be inserted, eg

```
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = sprintf('%s: %s%s', date('c'), $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL);
    file_put_contents('logs/insert_errors.txt', $error, FILE_APPEND);

    // don't forget to re-throw the exception otherwise your program will
    // continue execution
    throw $e; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Preamble**: As @Phil mentioned this has nothing to do with PDO.

There are two parts to your question:

**a) it is all in one connected line**

The reason is quite obvious, you are not adding a new line character at the end. What that character(s) is(are) depend on your OS, but PHP solves that for you with the PHP_EOL constant that you can just append to the end of your string.

**b) you want a timestamp at the beginning of each line**

Again, the issue is because you didn't put it there. Just adding the output of `date('r')` before printing out the message should be enough.

## The real solution: a real logger

You may want to look at using a complete logging solution for your code. Someting like [log4php](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/%E2%80%8E), for example.

### Homebrew solution

Alternatively, if that is too much, you could build your own logger. A good small example one can be found in the [comments of the documentation of PHP's `error_log` function](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php#86651) that I adapted for your needs:

```
Class Log { 
    const ERROR_DIR = '/home/site/error_log/db_errors.log'; 

    // Log PDO errors
    public function error($msg) { 
        $date = date('r'); 
        $log = sprintf('%s: %s%s', $date, %msg, PHP_EOL); 
        error_log($log, 3, self::ERROR_DIR); 
    }

    // shortcut for PDO exceptions
    public function exception($e) {
        $this->error($e->getMessage())
    } 
} 

try {
    $log = new log(); 
    $log->error($msg); //use for general messages
} except (Exception $e)
    $log->exception($e); //use for exceptions
}
```